# Retornar id ou saber nome do objeto dinâmico que foi clicado

Tags: c#

Olá! Estou aprendendo agora a criar objetos dinâmicos no C#, minha dúvida é de como retornar o Text do botão que eu cliquei por exemplo. Digamos que eu criei 10 objetos dinâmicos numerados(no caso o texto deles) de 0 a 9 e eu cliquei no 3, como vou saber que cliquei no 3?
Oque eu fiz até agora:

[image]

Eu tentei fazer dando uma olhada no "e", se tinha algum valor guardado nele, mas pelo visto não é bem como eu pensava...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode compartilhar o evento entre eles +/- assim:

```
private void MeusBotoes(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e){
      Button botao = default(Button);
      botao = (Button)sender;

      switch (botao.Name){

        case "Button1":
           Interaction.MsgBox("Voce pressionou o botão 1");
        break;

        case "Button2":
           Interaction.MsgBox("Voce pressionou o botão 2");
        break;
           //etc
      }
 }
```

Comment: Já tinha encontrado algo na net bem parecido com o seu, mesmo assim obrigado, era isso mesmo! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20220544/pass-dynamic-button-id-to-click-event

Comment: eu ja usei isso uma vez mas para VBA, ótimo tutorias do [Macoratti](http://www.macoratti.net/vbn_evnt.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Pegue a propriedade desejada do `object sender`. Neste caso é o botão (lembre de converter para Botão).

Para o caso dos botões, deveria haver um for para criar todos eles.

Comment: Mas... Que propriedade é essa? Eu já fiz um botão que replica os outros entendeu? Oque eu preciso agora, é ao clicar nos outros, saber em qual estou clicando, identificando eles pela propriedade Text, entende?

Comment: Não sei se notou, mas ela está nos parâmetros do método `boton_click(object sender, EventArgs e)`.

Comment: Eu sou muito iniciante no C# não entendi nada